# how to check update query

Tags: iphone

i want to add ycount field to 1;

ie ycount=ycount+1;

this is not working

```
[self Check_Create_DB];
sqlite3 *database; 
NSString *sqlTmp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update images set ycount=ycount+1 where imgid= '%d'",idimg ];
NSLog(@"%@",sqlTmp);
const char *sqlstmt=[sqlTmp UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *cmp_sqlstmt;
int returnvalue=sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sqlstmt,-1,&cmp_sqlstmt,NULL);
NSLog(@"return value.....%d",returnvalue);
if(returnvalue == SQLITE_OK)
{           
    sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt,1,ycount+1);
}
```

what is the error in this code

Comment: is ur image id string? if not then tell me

Comment: sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt,1,ycount+1);i think error here no error is showing and record is notupdating here sqlite3_bind_int(cmp_sqlstmt,1,ycount+1) i simply write ycount+1

Comment: imgid is string pls check this http://pastebin.com/EZDa9ajH

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
NSString *sqlTmp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update images set ycount=%i where imgid= '%d'", ycount+1,idimg ];
```

Comment: ur code showing error my requirement is add 1 to the value of ycount field in table

Comment: Oh sorry for the mistake! Thanks for the comment Jennis and Thanks for the edit Saad

Comment: yeah baiju u'r rite, but uiroshan not has given u code. jst suggestion, you may first get the count in some other variable and then give it in parameter.